# How does apache match authentication/authorization information with subsequent http requests from same user?

Tags: apache, authentication, cookies

When you protect an area of your document root using either the server configuration or .htaccess, the server prompts for a username and password when someone requests those files from a browser. If the password matches the one from the authentication provider for that user, the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html says that apache will set environment variables for that user. In my case I'm building a php app, and using phpinfo() I gather that the environment variables set are are REDIRECT_AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME, AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME (Using active directory as authentication provider), and REMOTE_USER. I believe this is what prevents the user from being prompted again and again on each subsequent request.

What I don't understand is how apache matches requests from a user with the environment variables set for that user, and also when and how it knows how to clear those variables. I doesn't appear to use cookies, because I cleared all the cookies for the domain in question, and still it doesn't ask me to reauthenticate unless I actually close the browser.

Ultimately I'm going to be working with php to get the userid and to maintain state, but since php is getting the information from the apache information, I'd like to know about that context, and I don't seem to be able to find these details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the http headers your browser is sending. After you have supplied a username and password, your browser will continue sending those details to that site until your browser session ends, or longer if you tell your browser to remember the credentials.

Comment: Thank you, your answer moves me closer, but not all the way. I've had a look at the requests, and after I've authenticated the browser adds an "authorization" header along with what looks like a hashed value. So I assume that apache saves each environment in a hashtable and sends the key to the authenticated user, which the browser returns in subsequent requests. I can't find where in any of the responses that hash is sent from the server though. I'd also like to know where the hashtable is that keeps these environments, and whether or not apache cleans it out periodically.

Comment: No. Apache sends no authentication information back to the browser. The browser re-asserts the authentication in each subsequent request. In the case of basic (as opposed to digest) authentication, the value in the authorisation header is simply a base64 encoded representation of the username and password. The webserver base64 decodes the value and checks the username and password against what is stored on the server.

Comment: Ok, in that case, do you have any idea where the browser stores this information, and how long it keeps it for?

Comment: Ok that last comment was a bit daft (they're accessible under Advanced Settings -> Passwords and forms -> Manage Passwords). But there's something to this that we haven't reached yet. How does the browser know to send the authorization header in subsequent requests? The browser has my user name and password stored for this domain, but it doesn't just automatically insert the authorization header when I first open the browser and visit the domain.

Comment: Only after I've reached the prompt, auto-filled, and clicked submit, then it will automatically add the header on subsequent requests to that domain as long as the browser stays open. Must be some kind of browser side in memory environment I guess. Anyhow, thanks for the effort.